# ¿Cómo obtener la parte no seleccionada de una muestra?

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando en R.
Tengo un conjunto de datos. Digamos que es el siguiente:
`(1,4,7,4,8,9,4,3,8,9)`

Me gustaría seleccionar el **70%** mediante muestreo aleatorio. por ejemplo, obtengo `(4,8,9,4,3,8,9)`

El caso es que quiero también saber qué datos no se han seleccionado, es decir, quiero tener un vector con los datos del **30%** restante `(1,7,4)`. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Obviamente estoy hablando de un conjunto de datos mucho mayor que 10 elementos, de ahí mi problema.
Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no importa el volumen, el procedimiento más básico sería:

```
casos <- c(1,4,7,4,8,9,4,3,8,9)

seleccion <- sample(1:length(casos), length(casos)*.7)
casos_70 <- casos[seleccion]
casos_30 <- casos[-seleccion]
```

Con `sample(1:length(casos), length(casos)*.7)` obtenemos una muestra del 70% de números del 1 hasta la longitud de nuestro vector de selección, cuyos valores usaremos luego para seleccionar los casos de cada conjunto.

Comment: Asumiendo muestreos sin reemplazo que es la opción por defecto de `sample`. Sino la unión de casos_30 y casos_70 puede tener más elementos que longitud.